# EF Code First - IsConcurrencyToken()

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first

Simple, but yet mysterious for me: Why do [StringPropertyConfiguration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.modelconfiguration.configuration.stringpropertyconfiguration%28v=vs.103%29.aspx) (and all the other PropertyConfiguration) class(es) have 2 overloads for `IsConcurrencyToken()`?

The first:

`public StringPropertyConfiguration IsConcurrencyToken()`

> Configures the property to be used as
>   an optimistic concurrency token.

And the second:

`public StringPropertyConfiguration IsConcurrencyToken(bool?)`

> Configures whether or not the property
>   is to be used as an optimistic
>   concurrency token.

Why would you use one over the other? As I see it, there's no difference at all between those two overloads (atleast not when working with them)...

By using the first you would write something like:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Author>()
    .Property(x => x.Name)
    .IsConcurrencyToken();
```

And by using the second you would write:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Author>()
    .Property(x => x.Name)
    .IsConcurrencyToken(true/false/null);
```

Have I missed something?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

My opinion...

The `IsConcurrencyToken()` defaults to true to provide a simple, fluent manner to define the entity.

The `IsConcurrencyToken(bool?)` allows the author to definitively set the `ConcurrencyMode` of the entity. This is useful for advanced scenarios:

- Overriding the `[ConcurrencyCheck]` attribute on the POCO
- Allowing a convention (removed in EF 4.1 RTW) to enable/disable the `ConcurrencyMode` based on some custom convention

Finally, I think `IsConcurrencyToken(false)` is better than `IsNotConcurrencyToken()`.

Comment: +1 for the "IsConcurrencyToken(false) is better than IsNotConcurrencyToken()". It's the same but reading the second one too fast might make one think that the property IS a ConcurrencyToken (one might just "skip" the "NOT" while reading it fast).