# Entity Framework : update user fails

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core

I'm trying to update a user with a user repository service. I'm still using the `IdentityUser`, just modified it to use `int` as primary key instead of string/guid.

Everything works fine, until my `Update` throws an exception.

So this is my update method in my `BaseRepository` class:

```
public virtual void Update(T entity)
{
    EntityEntry dbEntityEntry = _context.Entry<T>(entity);
    dbEntityEntry.State = EntityState.Modified;
}

public virtual void Commit()
{
    _context.SaveChanges();
}
```

The call itself goes:

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("home/account/edit")]
public ActionResult Edit(User user)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        return View(user);

    string id = _userManager.GetUserId(User);
    user.Id = id.To<int>();

    _userService.Update(user);
    _userService.Commit();

    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

(nothing special I think)

So now, when it's in `Commit` to save my changes, it throws an exception:

> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbUpdateConcurrencyException: Database operation expected to affect 1 row(s) but actually affected 0 row(s). Data may have been modified or deleted since entities were loaded. See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=527962 for information on understanding and handling optimistic concurrency exceptions.

I thought, okay, I check the profiler, couldn't be that tricky.
Profiler shows me the statement, entity framework sent him:

```
exec sp_executesql N'SET NOCOUNT ON;
UPDATE [AspNetUsers] SET [AccessFailedCount] = @p0, [Birthday] = @p1, [ConcurrencyStamp] = @p2, [Email] = @p3, [EmailConfirmed] = @p4, [FirstName] = @p5, [Language] = @p6, [LastName] = @p7, [LockoutEnabled] = @p8, [LockoutEnd] = @p9, [MiddleName] = @p10, [NormalizedEmail] = @p11, [NormalizedUserName] = @p12, [PasswordHash] = @p13, [PhoneNumber] = @p14, [PhoneNumberConfirmed] = @p15, [SecurityStamp] = @p16, [TwoFactorEnabled] = @p17, [UserName] = @p18, [VerificationToken] = @p19
WHERE [Id] = @p20 AND [ConcurrencyStamp] = @p21;
SELECT @@ROWCOUNT;
',N'@p20 int,@p0 int,@p1 datetime2(7),@p2 nvarchar(4000),@p21 nvarchar(4000),@p3 nvarchar(256),@p4 bit,@p5 nvarchar(4000),@p6 nvarchar(4000),@p7 nvarchar(4000),@p8 bit,@p9 nvarchar(4000),@p10 nvarchar(4000),@p11 nvarchar(256),@p12 nvarchar(256),@p13 nvarchar(4000),@p14 nvarchar(4000),@p15 bit,@p16 nvarchar(4000),@p17 bit,@p18 nvarchar(256),@p19 nvarchar(4000)',@p20=1,@p0=0,@p1='1991-06-10 00:00:00',@p2=N'24fe11c5-a831-45ce-8960-16aa78b280df',@p21=N'24fe11c5-a831-45ce-8960-16aa78b280df',@p3=N'my@email.ch',@p4=0,@p5=N'Matthias',@p6=N'de-DE',@p7=N'Burger',@p8=0,@p9=NULL,@p10=NULL,@p11=NULL,@p12=NULL,@p13=NULL,@p14=NULL,@p15=0,@p16=NULL,@p17=0,@p18=NULL,@p19=NULL;
```

So, `[ConcurrencyStamp] = @p21` and `@p21=N'24fe11c5-a831-45ce-8960-16aa78b280df'`

Checked my record of that user...

`ConcurrencyStamp` is `22fa7d03-1382-4eee-8c17-878253fdf1c4`

So my questions are:

- What is that `ConcurrencyStamp` ?
- Why is Entity Framework filtering for it? He gets my User ID. Isn't that enough?
- Why has the user object another `ConcurrencyStamp` than the one in the database? When Entity Framework wants to filter for it, shouldn't they be the same?
- Does anybody have an idea? How could/should I fix it? Or am I doing something wrong?

**Update**:

Model (for now viewmodel, too):

```
public class User : IdentityUser<int>, IEntity
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string MiddleName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public DateTime Birthday { get; set; }
    public string Language { get; set; }

    public ICollection<MailBox> MailBoxes { get; set; } = new List<MailBox>();
    public string VerificationToken { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: can you show us your model \ viewmodel please

Comment: @SimonPrice updated :) model is for now the viewmodel, too. it's more or less for testing now.

Comment: Your code is strange. You use the ID of the logged in user, but the data of the passed user? This code attempts to always creates a user with the logged in users id. Also you seem to never be attaching the model. Did you treid attaching the model before updating it?

Comment: Yep, this is for updating the own profile-data. So the passed user IS the logged in user.

Comment: And do you pass the concurrency token (`ConcurrencyStamp`) back to action? It is used to check if the model you tried to update hasn't been updated from a different action. if the token is different, the update fails (because the concurrency token will become part of the where clause)

Comment: What does `IdentityUser<>` look like?

Comment: @StriplingWarrior: https://github.com/aspnet/Identity/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore/IdentityUser.cs, it's open source and part of the Identity framework

Comment: @Tseng - I see, I should really have created a viewmodel and mapped it later on to the User-class... Mhhh. Yes, the ConcurrencyStamp was not mapped, so it was a different one.. Now with the viewmodel it works, since the ConcurrencyStamp is the same one. - Thanks for the hints :)

Comment: @MatthiasBurger: You probably want to *include* the `ConcurrencyStamp` on your model, keep track of it in the UI, and then map it back when saving. Otherwise, two users could edit the object concurrently.

Comment: @StriplingWarrior, yes that's what I'm doing now :) (now, I understood what it does)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `ConcurrencyStamp` is there to prevent two people from making two different changes to the same user without being aware of one another's changes.

```
    /// <summary>
    /// A random value that must change whenever a user is persisted to the store
    /// </summary>
    public virtual string ConcurrencyStamp { get; set; } = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
```

In principle, this should be assigned once when creating a user, and (I'm assuming) there should be a mechanism like a trigger in the database that causes the value to change whenever the entry in the database gets updated.

From [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37362173/120955):

> If you look at the implementation of IdentityDbContext in the OnModelCreating() method, you'll find:
>
> ```
> builder.Entity<TUser>(b =>
> {
> ....
>     b.Property(u => u.ConcurrencyStamp).IsConcurrencyToken();
> ....
> ```

So Entity Framework is aware that this is supposed to be treated as a concurrency token. It checks the property's value along with the ID to ensure that the update fails if the user has been changed since that user object was loaded out of the database.

As to why the value isn't the same, that's something you'll probably have to figure out through debugging. Here are a few theories you might check:

1. Maybe the user object really was changed since it got loaded? If the user object gets loaded twice with its original values and then changed twice independently, then this would happen.
2. Maybe you're constructing the user object based on values passed into a web request, but you're not mapping the ConcurrencyStamp token based on the value that was there when you pulled it from the database, so it's keeping the randomly-generated GUID that it gets when it's first constructed?

Comment: it was nearly the second one. my view sent a new user-object with the updated data, that I tried to update to the database. Here was no `ConcurrencyStamp` set (mapped from the original object, since views are resetting the model), therefore a new ConcurrencyStamp was generated and for sure they didn't match.