What value to set ConcurrencyStamp in AspNetRoles table
I need to add some user roles as part of a data migration script.
The ConcurrencyStamp appears to be a GUID. Does anyone know if something special is needed here? Or can I just add any GUID value?

Does https://stackoverflow.com/q/34252640/120955 answer your question?

Why not create a DataSeeder that uses aUserManager to add users? Then you will not have to worry about these issues anymore

@MohammadAghazadeh: Seems like more work. How would I run it as part of a data migration?

When migrating data, you can add a GUID value to the ConcurrencyStamp field, but you need to make sure it is unique in your database. And it should be noted that if entity is modified, the value of the ConcurrencyStamp needs to be updated. You can create a SaveChangesInterceptor to automatically update the ConcurrencyStamp. Here is an example for your reference:
public class ConcurrencyStampInterceptor : SaveChangesInterceptor
{
    public override InterceptionResult<int> SavingChanges(DbContextEventData eventData, InterceptionResult<int> result)
    {
        UpdateConcurrencyStamps(eventData.Context);
        return base.SavingChanges(eventData, result);
    }

    public override ValueTask<InterceptionResult<int>> SavingChangesAsync(DbContextEventData eventData, InterceptionResult<int> result, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
    {
        UpdateConcurrencyStamps(eventData.Context);
        return base.SavingChangesAsync(eventData, result, cancellationToken);
    }

    private void UpdateConcurrencyStamps(DbContext context)
    {
        if (context == null) return;

        foreach (var entry in context.ChangeTracker.Entries<IdentityRole>())
        {
            if (entry.State == EntityState.Modified || entry.State == EntityState.Added)
            {
                entry.Entity.ConcurrencyStamp = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
            }
        }

        foreach (var entry in context.ChangeTracker.Entries<IdentityUser>())
        {
            if (entry.State == EntityState.Modified || entry.State == EntityState.Added)
            {
                entry.Entity.ConcurrencyStamp = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
            }
        }
    }
}

When I change the name of the role:
public async Task UpdateRoleNameAsync(string oldRoleName , string newRoleName)
{
     var role = await _context.Roles.SingleOrDefaultAsync(r => r.Name == oldRoleName);

     if (role != null)
     {
               
         role.Name = newRoleName;
         role.NormalizedName = newRoleName.ToUpper();
         await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
     }
     else
     {
         throw new InvalidOperationException($"Role '{oldRoleName}' not found.");
     }
}

The relevant GUID has been changed:



Why would I bet updating a role? ASP.NET Core Identity should handle all these details, no? All I'm doing is adding a new role.

From the source code https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/main/src/Identity/Extensions.Stores/src/IdentityRole.cs we can see that in IdentityRole , the configuration of ConcurrencyStamp is nullable, so you can set it to null or a unique guid value. while in IdentityUser we can see that ConcurrencyStamp is assigned a guid value by default https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/main/src/Identity/Extensions.Stores/src/IdentityUser.cs. If you want identity to handle all these details, you can submit feedback for follow-up processing https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues.
